# How do I trigger a click event on a button within a popup?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I have a button in a popup and I want to be able to call a method in my vue component, when it is clicked. I am already using vue leaflet, but in this case I have to use leaflet's native popup functions.

I have tried using this L.DomEvent and using the popupopen event but since I have so many popups, the onclick gets called several times.

```
L.popup().setLatLng(bounds.getCenter()).setContent(this.getPopupDisplayContent()).openOn(map);
```

```
getPopupDisplayContent() {
  return (
   `<div><button type="button" id="add-button">Add</button></div>`
  );
}
```

Comment: you can use `@click="methodName"` event binding

Comment: I tried that and it doesnt work.

Comment: If you can add your code for modal and its parent then I can try

Comment: It's difficult to debug this problem without seeing the rest of your code.